# What are these little blue creatures following me?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have no idea what it is. I'm a level 12 (almost 13) monk. 4 of these little blue guys have been following me since before I defeated the Skeleton King. What are they?

Answer (score 8):

That's the special effect of the [Nagelring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/nagelring)

Before patch 2.4, it was possible to get this at lvl 11. It is now a possible drop starting at level 40, wearing it summons up to 4 Fallen Lunatics (pictured below) every few seconds.

[image: Screenshot showing blue summons]

Comment: and it will run to enemy and explode, dealing quite a huge damage, very useful for early game to fight boss and farming

Comment: Se0ng11 what do you mean by "farming"? I haven't experienced farming yet.

Comment: Farming in most, if not all loot-based games like Diablo, is killing monsters as quickly and efficiently as possible to get more loot.

Comment: Additionally, due to their aid in farming, this is a great item to have Kanai's Cube absorb the effect from, if you have the Reaper of Souls expansion.